# How to plot using ListPlot and FindRoot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica, now I have an expression
`Implicit\[Omega]Zero`

with some parameters $\lambda1,\mu rr,\theta s,b0,a,b1,\omega$

Now I want to find the $\omega(a)$ for the solution `Implicit\[Omega]Zero==0` for

```
params = {\[Lambda]1 -> 1, \[Mu]rr -> 0.05, \[Theta]s -> \[Pi]/2,  b0 -> .01, a -> a0, b1 -> .1}
```

Here is my try:

```
params = {\[Lambda]1 -> 1, \[Mu]rr -> 0.05, \[Theta]s -> \[Pi]/2, 
b0 -> .01, a -> a0, b1 -> .1}
Azero[a0_, \[Omega]_] = Implicit\[Omega]Zero /. params
ListPlot[
 Table[{i, FindRoot[Azero[i, \[Omega]] == 0, {\[Omega], 2}]}, {i, 3, 
   5, 1/2000}]]
```

Here I know the zero will be around 2.
But it didn't work, I want to get a plot of $\omega(a)$,any suggestion will be appreciated.

If you need what is `Implicit\[Omega]Zero`:

```
B[\[Theta]_] = (b0 b1 E^((\[Theta] \[Lambda]1)/\[Omega]))/(
  b1 E^((\[Pi] \[Lambda]1)/(4 \[Omega])) + 
   b0 (-E^(((\[Pi] \[Lambda]1)/(4 \[Omega]))) + 
      E^((\[Theta] \[Lambda]1)/\[Omega])));
Fb = a Integrate[
    B[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], \[Theta]s, 2 \[Pi] - \[Theta]s}] // 
  Simplify
Lb = a^2 Integrate[
    Sin[\[Theta]] B[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], \[Theta]s, 
     2 \[Pi] - \[Theta]s}] // Simplify
Implicit\[Omega]Zero = -(\[Mu]rr \[Omega] + Lb) // Simplify
```

Comment: What is the definition for `Implicit\[Omega]Zero`? We need executable code to play with.

Comment: @BobHanlon This is a complicate definition, I have posted the code in my question if you need it

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

B[θ_] = (b0 b1 E^((θ λ1)/ω))/(b1 E^((\
π λ1)/(4 ω)) + 
     b0 (-E^(((π λ1)/(4 ω))) + 
        E^((θ λ1)/ω)));

Fb = a Integrate[
     B[θ], {θ, θs, 2 π - θs}] // 
   Simplify;

Lb = a^2 Integrate[
     Sin[θ] B[θ], {θ, θs, 
      2 π - θs}] // Simplify;

ImplicitωZero = -(μrr ω + Lb) // Simplify;

params = {λ1 -> 1, μrr -> 1/20, θs -> π/2, 
   b0 -> 1/100, a -> a0, b1 -> 1/10};

Azero[a0_, ω_] = ImplicitωZero /. params;

root[i_?NumericQ] :=
 ω /. 
  FindRoot[Azero[i, ω] == 0, {ω, 2}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

Using [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
data = Table[{i, root[i]}, {i, 3, 5, 1/100}];

ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Using [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Off[FindRoot::precw]

Plot[root[i], {i, 3, 5}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to vary a parameter, include the parameter as an argument to the functions

```
params = {μrr -> 1/20, θs -> π/2, b0 -> 1/100, a -> a0, 
   b1 -> 1/10};

Azero[a0_, ω_, λ1_] = ImplicitωZero /. params;

root[i_?NumericQ, λ1_?NumericQ] := ω /. 
  FindRoot[Azero[i, ω, λ1] == 0, {ω, 2}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

Off[FindRoot::precw]

Manipulate[
 Plot[root[i, λ1], {i, 3, 5},
  PlotRange -> {0, 6}],
 {{λ1, 1}, 0.05, 2, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there any chance to use Manipulate to get the plots for different parameters (e.g different $\lambda 1$)